# Box2d. Can I make a revolute joint between a static box and a dynamic chain shape?

Tags: c++, box2d

In Box2D can I make a revolute joint between a static box and a dynamic chain shape as in the image below? I would like to be able to rotate the chain shape using a revolute joint with a  motor.
Also does it matter where the joint is on the bodies? Can it be *not* on the actual shape but outside it somewhere?

[image]

The following code produces the two fixtures but there is no revolute joint between them

```
    b2BodyDef bd2;
    b2Body* ground = world->CreateBody(&bd2);

    b2PolygonShape shape;
    const b2Vec2 vertices[4] = {
        b2Vec2(-40, -30),
        b2Vec2(40, -30),
        b2Vec2(40, 30),
        b2Vec2(-40, 30) };
    shape.Set(vertices, 4);
    ground->CreateFixture(&shape, 0.0f);


b2BodyDef bd;
bd.type = b2_dynamicBody;
b2Body* container = world->CreateBody(&bd);


b2Vec2 vs[4];
vs[0].Set(-11.583f, 20.806f);
vs[4].Set(-9.164f, -19.383f);
vs[6].Set(9.164f, -19.383f);
vs[8].Set(11.342f, 0.0f);

vs[4].Set(11.583f, 20.806f);

b2ChainShape chain;
chain.CreateChain(vs, 4);
container->CreateFixture(&chain, 0.0f);

b2RevoluteJointDef revoluteJointDef;
revoluteJointDef.bodyA = ground;
revoluteJointDef.bodyB = container;
revoluteJointDef.collideConnected = false;
revoluteJointDef.localAnchorA.Set(0, 0);
revoluteJointDef.localAnchorB.Set(0, 0);
b2RevoluteJoint* m_joint = (b2RevoluteJoint*)world->CreateJoint(&revoluteJointDef);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint anchor can be anywhere, it is not related to the fixture shapes in any way. You can even have two bodies with no fixtures at all and make a joint between them.

So yes, you can make a revolute joint between a static box and a dynamic chain shape. The issue you will come across though is that when a body only has a chain shape, it has no mass because the shape has no volume. When it has no mass, Box2D considers it to have infinite rotational inertia and it will not rotate.

You can get around this by adding a dummy fixture that does have volume (eg. a polygon or circle) to the same body. You can set the fixture to be a sensor so it causes no collision response (or set the collision filter flag bits all to zero).

If you really don't want to have any other fixture on the body, you could also manually set the values for the 'mass data' of the body with b2Body::SetMassData, but you'll need to know what values to set. The easiest way to find those values is to first create the dummy fixture, get the values with GetMassData, destroy the fixture, then SetMassData the values back.